# Change background color of listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using ListView inside a ViewFlipper as follows:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+Category/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:entries="@array/options"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
</ViewFlipper>
```

I want to change the background color of the ListView.
I have only 5 items in the options array and they do not fill the screen. So, the remaining part of the listView appears in the default grey color. I want to change this default color. I read about cacheColorHint attribute in questions posted by others related to this. But it did not work out. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check (using hierarchyviewer) that the android listView fills the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

Set a selector as the background of your ListView:

```
ListView mylw = findViewById(R.id.mylistView);
//Do not use reserved  android or java identifiers as your id or variable!
mylw.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thexmlbelow);
```

Drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="Background Color" />
    <item android:drawable="Background Color when pressed" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `layout_height="wrap_content"` (and `layout_width="wrap_content"` also if need) for your ListView and change the "default grey color" like you said by set the background for ViewFlipper.